# How to Display limited number of serach items in a single row using php ..(I have to display 6 items in single row n remaining in next row )

Tags: php, mysql

```
 <table class="coll activities" align="left" style="margin-top:15px;">

                    <tr>


<?php

$split = 0;
$result1=$conn->query("select * from subcategory where subcategory.maincat_id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());






while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc())

    {               

 $subid=$row1['subcat_id'];

 $sname=$row1['subcat_name'];

  $image=$row1['image'];

 $rowHTML = ' <a href="showresult.php?mid= <?php echo $id;?> &sid= <?php echo $subid;?> " title=" <?php echo $sname;?> ">';


  $rowHTML .= "< ?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64, '.  base64_encode($image)  .' "/>' ;?> <br />";


   $rowHTML .= "<?php echo $sname;?>";

  $rowHTML .= " </a> <br>";

echo $rowHTML;

                                $split++;   
                                if ($split%4==0){
                                echo '</tr><tr>';
                                }



                               }
                            ?>
                </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to format the code correctly and add your problem case to the question itself instead of just the title.

Comment: What is the problem? You already seem to have that, just change 4 to 6 and generate valid html.

Comment: That i know sir...only i have to  change the number ...now just  i have posted original code please tell me

Answer (score 0):

Create an iteration variable, increase that in each step inside a loop and check if `% 6 == 1`. If so, begin new row.

```
$i = 1;

echo '<table>';
while (...) {
    echo $i % 6 == 1 ? '<tr>' : ''; // 1st, 7th, 13th loop, create new table row

    // rest of your code
    $i++;
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?php
                    $result1=$conn->query("select * from subcategory where subcategory.maincat_id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
                    $i = 1;
                                            while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc())
                        {               
                               $subid=$row1['subcat_id'];
                               $sname=$row1['subcat_name'];
                               $image=$row1['image'];

                            if( $i % 6 == 0) {          
                            echo "<table><tr><td>";
                            ?>

                            <div  class="Column" style="background-color:#eee; border:1px solid #ccc" id="sl">
                            <a href="showresult.php?mid=<?php echo $id;?>&sid=<?php echo $subid;?>" title="<?php echo $sname;?>">
                            <center> 
                            <?php echo'<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,' .  base64_encode($image)  . '"/>';?><br />
                            <?php echo $sname;?>
                            </center>
                            </a>
                            </div>

                           <?php echo "</td></tr>"; } else { ?>

                           <div  class="Column" style="background-color:#eee; border:1px solid #ccc" id="sl">
                            <a href="showresult.php?mid=<?php echo $id;?>&sid=<?php echo $subid;?>" title="<?php echo $sname;?>">
                            <center> 
                            <?php echo'<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,' .  base64_encode($image)  . '"/>';?><br />
                            <?php echo $sname;?>
                            </center>
                            </a>
                            </div>




                          <?php $i++;  } echo "</table>" }  ?>
```

Comment: Is going out of div the above all code is giving error..I just have to split it to new row if it reaches to 6 ..

Comment: where is ur div in above code paste ur full code @NasruddinSayyad

Comment: http://www.kipon9.com/categories.php?n=Shopping%20Malls    have look on this url....only  first 5 columns are going down n in 6th column remaining rows are splitting out

Answer (score 0):

'

```
                    <?php
                    $result1=$conn->query("select * from subcategory where subcategory.maincat_id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
                    while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc())
                        {               
                               $subid=$row1['subcat_id'];
                               $sname=$row1['subcat_name'];
                               $image=$row1['image'];



                            ?>

                            <div  class="Column" style="background-color:#eee; border:1px solid #ccc" id="sl">
                            <a href="showresult.php?mid=<?php echo $id;?>&sid=<?php echo $subid;?>" title="<?php echo $sname;?>">
                            <center> 
                            <?php echo'<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,' .  base64_encode($image)  . '"/>';?><br />
                            <?php echo $sname;?>
                            </center>
                            </a>
                            </div>

                           <?php
                        }


                           ?>
```

```
  </div>'
```

Comment: Please tell me how could i fixed number of items in a single row and the remaining item needs to be go on next row.

Comment: Sir,but it increases the time complexity of the code that  u have given. And it is displaying a single item in a row.